# Let $f(x) = 4x - x^2$. Suppose $B = Ran(f)$. Find set $A$ such that function $f \restriction A$ is one-to-one and onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by the formula
>   $f(x) = 4x - x^2$ Let $B = Ran(f)$
>
> Find a set $A ⊆ \mathbb R$ such that $f \restriction A$ is a one-to-one, onto function
>   from A to B

Notation:

$$f \restriction A = f \cap (A \times B)$$
$f'(x) = 4 - 2x$

We have $4 - 2x = 0 \implies x = 2$.

Then if we let $A = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x ≥ 2\}$, the function $f \restriction A : A \rightarrow B$ will be one-to-one and onto.

My questions:

1. Is my choice of $A$ correct?
2. If it is correct, how to prove it? (I tried to take $a,b \in A$ and then let $(f \restriction A)(a) = (f \restriction A)(b)$, but it leads me nowhere)
3. If it is not correct, then what will the $A$ be? Can you prove it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is correct. First note that $B=(-\infty,4]$. This is because $f$ is continuous, it is bounded above by $4$ (which is attained when  $x=2$) and unbounded below. Next note that $f(A)=B$ by a similar argument using continuity. But $A$ is not unique. You can also take $A=(-\infty,2]$.

Note that $f '(x) <0$ for  $x <2$. This make $f$ strictly decreasing on $(2,\infty)$, Hence also on $A$ (by continuity). This implies that $f$ is one-to-one on $A$.

Comment: @Nelver I have added some details.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to show that $f$ is one-to-one without calculus?

Comment: Surely. If $4x-x^{2}=4y-y^{2}$ with $x,y \in A$ then $x^{2}-y^{2}=4x-4y$ which gives $(x-y)(x+y-4)=0$. Hence $x=y$ or $x+y=4$. But $x,y \geq 2$ so $x+y=4$ also implies $x=y=2$. So $x=y$ in any case.  @Nelver

Comment: Great, thank you one more time!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

0) $y= -(x-2)^2+4$;

Parabola with vertex $(2,4)$ opening downward.

1)$A=[2,\infty)$;

2) $f|A$ is one to one:

$-(a-2)^2+4=-(b-2)^2+4$;

$(b-2)^2-(a-2)^2=0$;

$((b-2)+(a-2))((b-2)-(a-2))=0;$

$(b+a-4)(b-a)=0;$

Implies $b=a$, or

$b+a=4$; Since $a,b \ge 2$ we get

$a=b=2$;

3)$f(A)=[4,-\infty)=:B$;

4) $A=(-\infty,2]$ ; Proceed similarly .